# Break long drawn text to multiple lines with Pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm creating a small python program that draws text on a small 128x48 image.
It works fine for text that only reaches width of 120, but I can't figure out how to have longer text split into an additional line. How do I go about doing so?

I've attempted using textwrap3, but I couldn't get it to work with Pillow.

The program creates 128x48 images files with a black background and yellow centered text, that is later supposed to be viewed on a device that outputs up to 480i, so simply making the text **much** smaller to fit additional text width won't be helpful. The font currently used is Arial 18.

Here's the current code used to create the image:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

AppName = "TextGoesHere"
Font = ImageFont.truetype('./assets/Arial.ttf', 18)
img = Image.new('RGB', (128, 48), color='black')
d = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

# Get width and height of text
w, h = d.textsize(AppName, font=Font)

# Draw text
d.text(((128-w)/2, (48-h)/2), AppName, font=Font, fill=(255, 255, 0))

img.save('icon.png')
```

The above code outputs the image like this:

[image: a busy cat]

Longer text with width bigger then the image outputs like this (LongerTextGoesHere):

[image: a busy cat]

The wanted result should be simular to this:

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: Are there really no spaces between your words? How will anyone know where to split them sensibly? Have you considered varying the size of the font as well as spreading over multiple lines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's some code that uses binary search with PIL/Pillow to break the text into pieces that fit.

```
def break_fix(text, width, font, draw):
    if not text:
        return
    lo = 0
    hi = len(text)
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo + hi + 1) // 2
        t = text[:mid]
        w, h = draw.textsize(t, font=font)
        if w <= width:
            lo = mid
        else:
            hi = mid - 1
    t = text[:lo]
    w, h = draw.textsize(t, font=font)
    yield t, w, h
    yield from break_fix(text[lo:], width, font, draw)

def fit_text(img, text, color, font):
    width = img.size[0] - 2
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    pieces = list(break_fix(text, width, font, draw))
    height = sum(p[2] for p in pieces)
    if height > img.size[1]:
        raise ValueError("text doesn't fit")
    y = (img.size[1] - height) // 2
    for t, w, h in pieces:
        x = (img.size[0] - w) // 2
        draw.text((x, y), t, font=font, fill=color)
        y += h

img = Image.new('RGB', (128, 48), color='black')
fit_text(img, 'LongerTextGoesHere', (255,255,0), Font)
img.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I have a small question about that, what if I want these chunks of text to be cut into different lines while also "preferably" get cut on spaces if there are any, so it conserves its meaning

Comment: @FrenchNoodles I answered the question as asked.  If you have a different question, ask it - you may reference this one if you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that pretty simply without needing to code any Python if you use **ImageMagick** which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows. So, just in Terminal:

```
convert -size 128x48 -background black -font Arial -fill yellow -gravity center caption:"Some Text" result.png
```

[image]

Or, with a longer text string:

```
convert -size 128x48 -background black -font Arial -fill yellow -gravity center caption:"Some Really Really Long Text" result.png
```

[image]

If you really, really want to write Python, **Wand** is a Python binding for **ImageMagick** and the function names will mirror those used above.

Comment: I prefer using PIL or Pillow though, to avoid the need of an external dependency.