# How to define text field in python (Pillow preferred)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, python-3.7

I want to define an rectangular area on top of an image, that has got a specific width and a specific height and in which a text should be pasted. I want the text to stay inside of this text field. If the text is longer, its size should be decreased and at one point it should be converted into a multiline text. How can I define such a text field using Pillow in python3?
I am looking for a clean and minimalist solution.

Sadly, I have no idea how to do this, since I am very new to python. I also didn't find any helpful and fitting information on how to do this, in the Internet. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at Mark Ransom's answer and mine here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/58042039/2836621

Comment: Ok, seems too fit my problem, thanks!