# PIL text exceeds desired length

Tags: python, image, text, python-imaging-library, maxlength

Today I have a question in relation of some of the PIL modules, specifically: the Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont. My problem starts when trying to write on an image with the ImageDraw module:

The text exceeds the length limit I desire, for example:
[image: Example of text exceeding the lenght I want]

And I want something just like this (example is done with paint just to trasmit the idea)

[image: Expected result.]

Also, there aren't parameters to do what I want, at least with the function `text` and based on this [web](https://blog.pythonlibrary.org/2021/02/02/drawing-text-on-images-with-pillow-and-python/).
(Theese are the parameters)
[image]

And finally, here's my code:

```py
from PIL import Image,ImageDraw, ImageFont


#import file
picture = Image.open("examplefile.png");

#start drawing
d1 = ImageDraw.Draw(picture)

#import font
myFont = ImageFont.truetype('./Roboto/Roboto-Medium.ttf', 50)

#set text
text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet quod voluptas illum illo quas at inventore eos nostrum. Voluptatem commodi dignissimos sed consequatur. Rerum qui numquam nobis quo distinctio."
# time to write.

#        x  y  text     color (black)   font (robot semi-bold)
d1.text((0, 0), text, fill =(0, 0, 0),font=myFont)
```

I have tried with conunting words or characters... but I hope there's a better solution.

Thanks for your time reading this question.

Comment: You will need to manually wordwrap the text to fit into the box. The size of a text string if it were rendered can be determined ahead of time by using the PIL's [`ImageDraw.textsize()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.textsize) function.

Comment: Almost a duplicate of [Break long drawn text to multiple lines with Pillow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58041361/5987).