# Breaking Up Long Text Using Pillow

Tags: python, image, text, python-imaging-library, word-wrap

By default, while writing text, Pillow in Python returns text which is cut off from the sides. I want to make it so that the text is cut off from the last word i.e. word wrap the text.

Current:

[image: Current Text]

Expected:

[image: Expected Text]

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58176967/3742786) to be useful but it breaks text from the last letter instead of a word.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my code to demo how to split word from a long string, but with left justification only, and with/without edge alignment. You can change following code to make it with center justification, and how many padding along edges.

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

def split(string):
    return string.split()

def draw_text(string, font="cour.ttf", size=16, width=320, height=240,
        background=(255, 255, 255, 0), color='black', edge=False,
        justification='center', mode="RGBA"):

    im = Image.new(mode=mode, size=(width, height), color=background)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im, mode)
    font = ImageFont.truetype(font=font, size=size)

    words = split(string)
    length = len(words)
    lines, start = [], 0

    for i in range(length):
        line = ' '.join(words[start:i+1])
        w, h = font.getsize(line)
        if (w > width):
            lines.append(' '.join(words[start:i]))
            start = i
        elif i == length-1:
            lines.append(line)

    len_lines = len(lines)
    dy = (height-h)//(len_lines-1)
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if edge and (i != len_lines-1):
            words = line.split()
            length = len(words)
            delta = (width - sum(map(lambda x:font.getsize(x)[0], words)))//(length-1) if length>1 else 0
            x = 0
            for j, word in enumerate(words):
                draw.text((x, i*dy), word, fill=color, font=font)
                x += font.getsize(word)[0]+delta
        else:
            draw.text((0, i*dy), line, fill=color, font=font)

    im.show()    # using im.save to save image to file

width, height = 960, 120
font, size = "arial.ttf", 32
align = True
string = (
    "Python is an easy to learn, powerful programming language. "
    "It has efficient high-level data structures and a simple "
    "but effective approach to object-oriented programming.").strip()

draw_text(string, font=font, size=size, width=width, height=height, edge=True)
draw_text(string, font=font, size=size, width=width, height=height, edge=False)
```

[image]

[image]